# Pegar uma string de uma textbox quando pressionada a tecla Enter

Tags: c#, winforms

É possível pegar uma string de uma textbox quando pressionada a tecla enter? Se sim, como? Gostaria que deixassem exemplos de código pois sou bastante novo neste mundo das WinForms...

Comment: Explique melhor o que é "pegar uma `string` de uma `TextBox`". Pegar onde? Fazer o que com isto? A pergunta está muito abstrata. Coloque um exemplo do que está fazendo e qual é o seu problema.

Comment: Eu quero que a input do textbox seja pegado quando a tecla enter seja pressionada.

Comment: Isto não acrescentou nenhuma informação nova, você só repetiu o que já tinha escrito. Faça o que eu falei.

Comment: É simples. Eu estou tentando criar uma textbox que, quando pressionado enter dentro da textbox, o input que o utilizador escreveu na textbox. Só isso, não é tão complexo...

Comment: Mas não dá para saber o que você quer fazer com isto. A resposta dada foi um chute e você considerou ela adequada porque você não queria fazer nada útil com esta informação.

Comment: É simples a questão. Se você não percebe, não tenho culpa.

Comment: Se é simples, por que você não descreve ela corretamente? Falta informações para que possa ser dada uma resposta correta. O que lhe responderam não serve para nada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode associar o código que vai utilizar o conteúdo do *TextBox* com um evento que seja disparado quando uma tecla é pressionada enquanto o *TextBox* possui o foco.

Você pode usar o evento **KeyDown** do componente **TextBox**. Para tanto, selecione o componente no formulário e, na janela *Properties*, clique no botão apontado para ver a lista de eventos, localize o evento *KeyDown* e dê duplo-clique nele:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No arquivo *NomeDoForm.cs* o visual studio vai gerar um código mais ou menos assim:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

E também vai associar este método ao evento *KeyDown* do componente *TextBox* (neste caso, o nome do meu TextBox é *textBox1*).

Veja no arquivo *NomeDoForm.Designer.cs* como o Visual Studio fez isso:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ...
        this.textBox1.KeyDown += 
                    new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
        ...
    }
}
```

Por fim, no corpo do método que o Visual Studio gerou em *NomeDoForm.cs*, insira o código de tratamento do texto do TextBox. Exemplo:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
    }  
}
```

Observe então que não basta você escrever o código acima, este método precisa estar associado ao evento do componente textbox.

Estude como a programação de WinForms é orientada a eventos, procure compreender o código gerado pelo Visual Studio.

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo, o problema é que eu estou usando o Xamarin Studio. Tem como fazer isso por ele?

Comment: Consegui associar o evento com a textbox. Mas não funciona...

Comment: @DavidAmaral Então deve ser um bug do compilador. Esses compiladores de C# são muito instáveis ;-) Vamos torcer para aparecer alguém com a solução para um problema descrito como "não funciona".

Comment: Eu estou a usar o Xamarin que, pelos vistos, não tem o evento KeyDown. Apenas KeyPress e KeyRelease. Alguma forma de o fazer por KeyPress?